# Forming RequestHeader with Parameters

Tags: java, request-headers

```
GET /sap/sap.dll HTTP/1.1
Host: www17.mywebsite.co.in
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic c4FtdWVsajE6Q2hddmdlQDErfw==
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: fl-cookies-accept=true; PDWPI-SSL-SESSION-COOKIE=8CocgSJ84xGfLABQVo8DZQ==BFZz5qWf+iGI6242re1eg-u4N9pGPnWnVKoK4nF6g2M=; PDWPI-SSL-SESSION-COOKIE=QKkkDzZ84xGfLABQVo8DZQ==9rU8IIgPbB50dk+PraQo2lcb1zp+AwPu2MGtqmyWGWE=
```

I need to form the request url with the following parameters. I have read that `conn.setRequestProperty` will not work for https request. Moreover I am behind a proxy server as well. Can someone throw some light to form the url as such?

Comment: I believe you can use setRequestProperty, but some properties may be overriden. Otherwise, there is Apache HttpClient: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/